# Apply for loop with variable

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to condense my code because I have a lot of repetitive coding happening. I will need to apply this same example many times over. I want to create a for loop but my variable needs to increase as well. Right now I have my variable increasing but I am unable to implement my cell data into the variable. I think I am double assigning var h. I can't figure out how to get around this. Thank you for your help.

**For Loop**

```
for (var j = 2; j<15; j++){eval("var polebrea" +j); 
var h = ("polebrea" +j) 
} 

h = document.getElementById("part1Table").rows[10].cells[2].innerHTML;
```

**Code Attempting To Implement**

```
polebrea2 = document.getElementById("part1Table").rows[10].cells[2].innerHTML;
polebrea3 = document.getElementById("part1Table").rows[10].cells[3].innerHTML;
polebrea4 = document.getElementById("part1Table").rows[10].cells[4].innerHTML;
polebrea5 = document.getElementById("part1Table").rows[10].cells[5].innerHTML;
```

(cont. to 15)

**Inserting Variable**

```
<script>document.write(polebrea2)</script>
```

Comment: Don't use `eval`. Create an array that you can index.

Comment: Use an object to store them in instead of creating a new variable for each. `object["polebrea" + j]`

Comment: Having dynamically named variables is a sign of bad design somewhere. Use a data structure that can hold a collection of something, like an object or array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring design dogma....use the string index form of property access to set your variables:

```
// window is a bad place for this....you should probably put it on another object e.g. var polbreas = {}; 
for (var i = 2; i<15; i++){
    window["polbrea"+i] = document.getElementById("part1Table").rows[10].cells[i].innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua, your answer was right on with what I was looking for and it works without changing anything. I actually came pretty close to this myself a couple of times but not sure where I was going wrong. Now all I have to do is use (document.write (polbrea2)) and it gives me that correct cell. I have other if statements that will pull the other numbers.

Answer (score -2):

While not necessarily good practice to do what you are doing, you could try this:

```
var createVariable = function( index ){
    var variableName = "polebrea" + index;
    var objName = document.getElementById("part1Table").rows[10].cells[index].innerHTML;
    return (variableName + " = " + objName + ";");
};

for (var j = 2; j<15; j++){
        var objToWrite = createVariable(j);
        console.log( objToWrite );
}
```